# Flutter Firebase Database child('.info/connected') always returns true

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I'm calling this when I press a button on my app.

```
await _rootRef.child(".info/connected").once().then((data){
  print("value: ${data.value}");
});
```

data.value returns true, either way my connection status. Ive database persistence as true, and reference keepsynced as true too... but with both false this happens too!
I need to make a listener for this or whats the matter :(

Ty so much

EDIT:
[image]
Database and rules, if any doubt remains about _rootRef. It's FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().
Any other screen or data yuo would need I'm here, ty for your time.

EDIT2: 
Here you have a repositoy with recreating the issue:
https://github.com/rubcc95/flutter-firebase

Also I've made a video about:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pbrtjS1r5fA

Comment: add a screenshot of ur database

Comment: For sure, added ty.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities?hl=en#section-connection-state     .info is an special location from database. If .info didn't exist i wouldn't recieve a bool true, i just would recieve a null, so it exist.

Comment: The value returned by `.info/connected` is not dependent on your JSON structure, nor on your security rules, disk persistence, or calling keepsynced. If you get `true` it means that the client is connected to a Firebase database server. If it seems to be doing something differently for you, please include the [minimal, exact/standalone steps that any of use can take to reproduce that behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry for take so long to response and thanks you as always for your time. I've updated the minimal you asked for... Ive realized if i remove the stream from MyHomePage it shows connected: false after 60 seconds. That made me answer if maybe I'm using .info/connect as a wrong purpose, because i just wanted to see if I had connection with the server at the moment I was making a query. Maybe .info/connnected gives you a true value if it is connected to a Firebase Database, either the cache or the server one. I'm searching deeper at the documentation now...

Answer (score 0):

you need a listen :)

```
await _rootRef.child(".info/connected").onValue.listen((event) {
        print("value: ${event.snapshot.value.toString()}");
      });
```